# Creating a google sheet with lookup values based on another google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I own a Google Sheet 'Transactions' containing transaction data without explicitly specifying actual transaction amount and using payment code instead. This is because I have shared this Google sheet with multiple people. This looks like as follows:-

[image]

Now I have another private (not shared with anybody) Google sheet 'Lookup' which contains mapping of payment code and actual currency amount as:-

[image]

Now what I desire is a third Google sheet which only I will have access to -- this should have the actual Amount column , basically it should perform lookup based on PaymentCode and fetch the actual value as shown in the following screenshot:-

[image]

I am new to Google Sheets so if there is any other built-in out-of-the-box feature for this kind of scenario, pls let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets call your sheets:

- private
- shared
- third

in your 3rd sheet run these formulae anywhere and allow access:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("private_url_or_id", "private!A1")

=IMPORTRANGE("shared_url_or_id", "shared!A1")
```

now when access is allowed and sheets are connected use this in A1 of your third sheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("shared_url_or_ID", "shared!A2:C"), IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 IMPORTRANGE("shared_url_or_ID", "shared!B2:B"), 
 IMPORTRANGE("private_url_or_ID", "private!A:B"), 2, 0))}, 
 "select Col1,Col4,Col3", 0))
```

---

[image]

Comment: reagrding "url_or_id" , how do I get id for a given Google Sheet file ?

Comment: Also -- names of individual "sheets" is constant Sheet1 in all the 3 Google Sheet documents , so I think =IMPORTRANGE("url_or_id", "private!A1") will have to be converted to =IMPORTRANGE("url_or_id", "private!Sheet1") ?

Comment: basically these are 3 different Google Sheet files each with a fixed sheet name as Sheet1.

Comment: @Dhiraj no, not `private!Sheet1` it will be `Sheet1!A2:C` sheetname!sheetrange

Comment: this sounds good , but this doesn't copy if a field has a checkbox in shared sheet. e.g. say instead of transaction date we had some boolean field -- which we wanted to get inm 'third' as well without any change. Is it a limitation of IMPORTRANGE that it can't get checkboxed field ?

Comment: for checkboxes you can run data validation in your third which will convert TRUE/FALSE into checkboxes

Comment: the issue is that if I specify checkbox in "shared" , "third" doesn't copy anything for that cell at all , it keeps showing blank (not even TRUE/FALSE values)

Comment: hard to tell where is the issue if I cant look at it directly... could be query issue so try to text it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVVnP.png